# How to get the memory-mapping (e.g. library) that contains a given address in Radare?

Tags: radare2

> How to get the memory-mapping (e.g. library) that contains a given address in Radare?

I've done a search in Radare for a specific string (`search.in = dbg.maps`), which resulted in an address.

Now, I want to know which memory-mapping the address corresponds to, e.g. is it libc?

How can I obtain the memory-mapping whose memory region contains the given address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the command `dm.` you can show the map name of the current address.
To change the current address to your desired one add `@ address`

For example:

`[0x7f8622478090]> dm. @ 0x00007f8622477000
0x00007f8622477000 - 0x00007f8622478000 * usr     4K s r-- /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so`

You can combine your search directly with the dm. command:

```
dm. @@/ STRING
```

Comment: Why does your 'dm.' command return multiple .so's?

Comment: Both are the same. The first one is the name and the other one the file itself. If you're a little bit familiar how to look at radare's code you can find this spot inside the file `libr/debug/map.c` in the function `print_debug_map_line`

Comment: Thank you @defragger. How come `ld-2.28.so` is only `r--`? In my case `libc-2.28.so` is also marked `r--`, which means it is only readable, but not executable?

Comment: Yes in my case `ld-2.28.so` has also the following maps: `0x00007f6e3273b000 - 0x00007f6e3273c000 - usr     4K s r-- /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so
0x00007f6e3273c000 - 0x00007f6e3275a000 * usr   120K s r-x /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so ; map.usr_lib_ld_2.28.so.r_x
0x00007f6e3275a000 - 0x00007f6e32762000 - usr    32K s r-- /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so ; map.usr_lib_ld_2.28.so.r
0x00007f6e32762000 - 0x00007f6e32764000 - usr     8K s rw- /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so /usr/lib/ld-2.28.so ; map.usr_lib_ld_2.28.so.rw
`

Comment: How do you get all those maps? I see only a few using the `dmm` command.

Comment: I used just `dm` that will print all memory maps of the target process. To get all names of the printed fields you can append `j` to your command to print it as json (`~{}` will indent that for you. So the command above would look like this: `dmj~{}`

Comment: thanks once again. What is the difference between `dm` and `dmm`? Also, `dmi` wants a library name: it doesn't accept libc-2.28.so, but wants libc. How can I output the list of all such "shortnames" that `dmi` accepts?